# Save changes to JSON with SimpleJSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, simplejson

I have a JSON file as follows:

```
{
  "volume" : "1.0"
}
```

I want to edit this to another value like 0.5 etc. When I use the following code I get strange results in my JSON file. It does write something to the JSON file but it writes strange symbols to the file with volume in between.

```
SimpleJSON.JSONNode node = SimpleJSON.JSONNode.Parse(Resources.Load<TextAsset>("JSON/Test/test").text);

// new value
node["volume"].AsFloat = 0.5f;

System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(File.Open("Assets/Resources/JSON/Test/test.json", 
FileMode.Create));

node.Serialize(bw);
```

What is wrong with my code?

I am using SimpleSON in an Unity project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this but forgot to post the answer so here it is.

```
    SimpleJSON.JSONNode node = SimpleJSON.JSONNode.Parse(Resources.Load<TextAsset>
    ("JSON/Test/test").text);

    node["volume"].AsFloat = 0.5f;

    File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Assets/Resources/JSON/Test/" + @"\audio.json", node.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TextWriter instead of BinaryWriter.